# Multiple arrays transformed to objects to one array with Node JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

For example I have this arrays:

```
a = [1, 2, 3];
b = ["a", "b", "c"];
```

I want to make one object from these arrays that would look like this:

```
c = [{
  a: 1,
  b: "a"
},
{
  a: 2,
  b: "b"
},
{
  a: 3,
  b: "c"
}];
```

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: I made one empty array containing certain number of objects like this c = [{
a: 0,
b: 0
},{
a: 0,
b: 0
},{
a: 0,
b: 0
}] 

and then with for loop i filed in data but this is really bad if I had 100+ arrays

Comment: Check Nikhil's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a for-loop like this:

```js
    var a = [1, 2, 3];
    var b = ["a", "b", "c"];

    var c = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i ++) {
        c[i] = {'a': a[i], 'b': b[i]};
    }
    console.log(c);
```

Comment: Thank you this solution is so simple and easy to understand for a beginner like me.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
let a = [1, 2, 3];
let b = ["a", "b", "c"];
let c = a.map((v,i) => ({a:v, b: b[i]}));
console.log(c);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to do something like this perhaps:

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3];
var b = ["a", "b", "c"];

var c = a.reduce((accumulator, e, index) => {
  return accumulator.concat({a: e, b: b[index]});
}, [])

console.log(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.forEach()` loop for that:

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3];
var b = ["a", "b", "c"];
var c = [];
a.forEach((item, index)=>{
  c.push({a: item, b: b[index]});
});
console.log(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take an object with an arbitrary count of properties and generate an array of objects.

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3],
    b = ["a", "b", "c"],
    result = Object
        .entries({ a, b })
        .reduce((r, [k, a]) => {
            a.forEach((v, i) => Object.assign(r[i] = r[i] || {}, { [k]: v }));
            return r;
        }, []);
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

## Traditional but compatible way

*Note: Most solutions in this page don't check if  variables `a` and `b`  have the same length*

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
var b = ["a", "b", "c"];

function combine(a,b){
        
    if (a.length === b.length){ // Check if both arrays have same length  
      var arr = []; // Make an empty array
      for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++){ // iterate every element of the array
          var obj = {} // Make an empty object
          obj["a"] = a[i];
          obj["b"] = b[i];
          arr.push(obj);
      }
    }else{        
        throw "Arrays don't have the same length";
    }
    
    return arr;
}

combine(a, b); // Use it like a function
```